# Saber se valor está no array sem comparação por igualdade!

Tags: array, c++

Tenho o seguinte código em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main (void){

           int e[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};       

           for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++){

                if ( i in e ) cout << e[i] ;

           }
    }
```

Tenho um array com **5** elementos numerados de 0 à 4
Tenho um laço `for` com 100 elementos numerados de 0 à 99

Em cada laço do `for` se para o número em questão, existe no *array* `e[5]`, uma combinação.

Em outras palavras, saber se existe no *array* (`IN`) uma combinação

No PHP, basta fazer

```
if ( i in e ) echo e[i] ;
```

Mas não sei como fazer em C++.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, tirando o `cout` este código é C e não C++, quase todo mundo aprende fazer C++ do jeito errado. E se fizesse em C++ seria tão simples quanto PHP, seria só usar uma função pronta, como o [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) por exemplo. Mas se quer do jeito difícil seria:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main () {
    int e[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};       
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (e[j] == i) {
                cout << i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aHh94Y). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hfecmglh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/ComparingContains.cpp).

Ou se for isto mesmo (e aí do jeito que faz em PHP é ruim) pode fazer de um jeito mais inteligente e performático:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main () {
    int e[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};       
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) if (e[i] >= 0 && e[i] < 100) cout << i;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wEbwoE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kbajuwdp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/ComparingRange.cpp).

Comment: Bom, no PHP, quando usamos o IN, o script faz uma busca interna e retorna a primeira combinação (se houver). O que eu estou querendo saber é se em C++ existe algo que faça a mesma coisa que o IN do PHP. Tem?

Comment: Acho que seria util mostrar como fica com `find`, que provavelmente é o que o AP estaria à espera de ver.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Tem algo que você não entendeu? Coloquei tudo isto na resposta. Mostrei que se fizer usando C++ de verdade tem como e mostre a função que faz, mas não entrei em detalhes porque porque o seu código não usa isto. E dei dois exemplos de como fazer usando C, que foi como você escreveu o código, um dele sem operador e função, então dá para fazer, mas não igual ao PHP, e mostrei que na verdade, em C, C++ ou PHP pode ser feito a mesma coisa de forma mais rápida e simples.

Comment: tem sim. Note que no teu primeiro exemplo, na saida teremos uma linha para cada volta interna do wile gerando várias repetiçoes. Já na segunda você não está fazendo as comparações! Cheguei a criar outro tópico explicando mais detalhado, porém ele foi bloqueado! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337218/retirar-repeti%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-la%C3%A7o-for?noredirect=1#comment681194_337218

Comment: @CarlosRocha eu respondi baseado no que você postou, a segunda resolve o problema desta pergunta de forma mais simples, na outra pergunta seu problema é completamente diferente desta, por isso eu escrevi `se for isto mesmo` porque alguma coisa me dizia que este código não era o que você queria, então esta resposta serve para esta pergunta, não para outra. Eu não posso responder sobre algo que não perguntou. Não tem como eu adivinhar o que quer sem você escrever exatamente qual é a dúvida. Tudo o que fiz é baseado no que postou.

Comment: Entendi. Mas sem querer ser chato. Mas já sendo. Na segunda opção, como ficaria a comparação? for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) if (e[i] >= 0 && e[i] < 100) cout << i; Comparaçao se os valores conferem? E por favor me perdoe. Na outra pergunta eu coinsegui ser mais conciso no que eu preciso realmete

Comment: De que comparação está falando? Está aí o código pronto, funcionando e fazendo o que pediu na pergunta. Vou editar e colocar *link* mostrando funcionando.

Comment: if (e[j] == i) {...}

Answer (score 1):

Complementando o que o @Maniero já disse, pode utilizar o `std::find` que faz parte da biblioteca `algorithms` para pesquisar se o elemento existe. O `find` recebe 3 valores, o elemento inicial, final, e o valor a ser pesquisado.

Transpondo isto para o seu código ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // inclusão do header associado
using namespace std;

int main (void){

       int e[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};       

       for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++){
            if (find(e, e + 5, i) != e + 5) cout << i << " "; 
            //   ^---^----^----^---- utilização do find
       }
}
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/X1qC5Z)

Neste exemplo o valor inicial foi definido através do ponteiro para o primeiro elemento com `e`, e o final definido também com um ponteiro, mas avançando a quantidade de elementos suficientes para ficar a seguir ao ultimo, o `e + 5`.

Como o `find` devolve um ponteiro para o elemento encontrado, ou para o fim caso não exista nenhum elemento igual, tem de comparar se esse ponteiro ficou no fim.

Uma utilização mais natural deste idioma é guardar o resultado da pesquisa num ponteiro/iterador para depois o usar quando quiser aceder ao elemento encontrado:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++){
    int *pesq = find(e, e + 5, i);
    if (pesq != e + 5) cout << *pesq << " ";
    //                           ^--- imprime o valor encontrado com base no ponteiro devolvido

}
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/P9onMP)

Como indicado pelo @MarioFeroldi em comentário, também pode usar `std::begin` e `std::end` para obter o inicio e fim de um array normal. Isso acaba por tornar o código mais flexivel pois define apenas o tamanho em um local:

```
int e[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};       

for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++){
    int *pesq = find(begin(e), end(e), i);
    //                 ^--------^
    if (pesq != end(e)) cout << *pesq << " ";
    //           ^---
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ryS8BP)

Outra solução possível e comum no mundo do C++ e não C, é utilizar um `vector` para armazenar os inteiros, o que altera ligeiramente a forma como o `find` tem de ser utilizado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> //vector também necessário agora

using namespace std;

int main (void){

       vector<int> e = {10,20,30,40,50};       

       for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++){
            if (find(e.begin(), e.end(), i) != e.end()) cout << i << " "; 
       }
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/tQFyZA)

Agora o inicio e fim da pesquisa foi construido com base no método `begin` e o `end` do `vector` que retornam iteradores para os elementos correspondentes.

Nota: os exemplos de código dados nesta resposta foram adaptados da [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

Comment: Detalhe: `std::begin` e `std::end` funcionam com arrays, então não precisa fazer `e + 5`, só `std::end(e)`.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Desconhecia esse pormenor, mas agradeço o comentário.